# OAuth between legacy PHP site and OWIN web api

Tags: php, asp.net, oauth, owin, hybridauth

I am working on a legacy PHP site that has been upgraded recently to use HybridAuth to support social login. Some new services are under development and are being done using ASP.NET Web API (and are on a subdomain of the php site).

What I'm struggling to figure out is how I can authorize access to these services from this legacy PHP site. It seemed like the right thing to do was to create a separate Authorization Service, but this doesn't seem to be the right approach when it comes to using existing external OAuth providers.

Is there some way I can proxy the `oauth_token` and `oauth_verifier` tokens that I get in the response from an external provider (say Twitter) to my web API service and get a valid bearer token back?